# Creating beanstalkd jobs on django model signals

Tags: django, beanstalkd

I want to create beanstalkd jobs when a django model is saved. For this I am listening to the model's post_save signal and the associated handler is creating a beanstalkd job like below for example (in `myapp/signals.py`):

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=MyModel)
def create_job(sender, **kwargs):
    beanstalk = beanstalkc.Connection(
        host='example.com',
        port=11300
    )
    beanstalk.use('test')
    beanstalk.puts('job');
```

However I do not like the fact that I am creating a new connection each time I receive a signal. My questions are:

1. Would that be good if I connected to beanstalkd outside the function, at the top of the module and reuse the connection instead?
2. However If I reused the connection and the connection broke for some reasons, the entire process would suffer, right? So, what would be a better solution here?

Comment: Can you use `try` and `except` blocks? Also, whenever I use a connection I like to use `with` blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I ended up following this approach:

I created a class inside common/util/beanstalkd_client.py:

```
from django.conf import settings
import beanstalkc


class _BeanstalkdClient:
    def __init__(self):
        self.beanstalk = beanstalkc.Connection(
            host=settings.BEANSTALKD.get('host'),
            port=int(settings.BEANSTALKD.get('port'))
        )

        self.job = None

    def watch(self, tube, ignore_default=True):
        self.beanstalk.watch(tube)

        if ignore_default:
            self.beanstalk.ignore('default')

    def use(self, tube):
        self.beanstalk.use(tube)

    def reserve(self):
        self.job = self.beanstalk.reserve()
        return self.job

    def put(self, payload):
        self.beanstalk.put(payload)


beanstalkd_client = _BeanstalkdClient()
```

This allows me to reuse the beanstalkd_client and handles the connection inside. Since python will always create one instance of a module, beanstalkd_client module will always have one connection to beanstalkd.

Then in my signals.py:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save, post_delete
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.conf import settings

from common.util.beanstalkd_client import beanstalkd_client

beanstalkd_client.use(settings.BEANSTALKD.get('my_tube_name'))


@receiver(post_save, sender=Address)
def es_create_index(sender, **kwargs):
    beanstalkd_client.put('my awesome job!')
```

However this still does not handle the 2nd point: What if the connection to beanstalkd is broken!